# Looking for a batch to clear onenote cache. Newbie at Batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, onenote

Thank you for any/all help, I am a newbie at batch files but I am trying to find a way to create a batch file that I can install on my end users computer that will clear onenote cache they using resources when they leave their OneNote open for a significant amount of time since they pretty much use onenote all day for information documentation and retrieval. to get to it you would type in the run window onenote /safeboot, but I can't get a batch to do that and maybe it can't be done.

Comment: When do you want this `onenote /safeboot` to be run? A reasonable time would seem to be on reboot/re-logon, but I've no idea what `onenote` is about. Had it for years. Never used it...

Comment: At logon would probably work, But I would like the user to be able to run it if they are having problems with it during the day also.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably not a task for a batch file, but for a scheduled task (just use its wizard to create one). set it to run regularly however convenient to you, eg. at login, or at 12am.

Answer (score 0):

[This microsoft article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/command-line-switches-in-microsoft-office-onenote-2007-HA010177833.aspx) indicates that the `/safeboot` switch opens Onenote in safe mode and *in that mode* the user can choose to clear the cache. It does not appear to be a *Onenote* option to clear the cache, though perhaps **Autoit** could be trained to do so.

It would appear that *onenote /safeboot* **allows** you to clear the cache, but it's a manual action to be taken. I'd suggest that unless **Autoit** can execute the clearing then exit, then random auto-execution may be a very bad idea.

The desktop shortcut is unhelpful in locating `onenote.exe`. Probably the best method is by executing, from the prompt,

```
dir /s onenote.exxe
```

I found my version (2010) at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\onenote.exe`

Under these circumstances, a batch file

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\onenote.exe" /safeboot
GOTO :EOF
```

can start a `Onenote` instance, offering the `clear cache` option. This may be useful during start-up, but may be useful at any time if offered as a desktop icon, for instance as the first screen it presents is the clear-cache option. You might construct an icon with the same graphic, but running the batch file, for instance...